# Creating readwrite field at runtime in Dataset - provider - clientdatatset

Tags: delphi

I am trying to create an additional field that is NOT ReadOnly at runtime in Delphi.  I have a TADOQuery with SQL on the lines of

```
SELECT *,CAST(0 AS BIT) AS CheckField FROM MyTable WHERE KeyField = :KeyValue
```

This links through a TDatasetProvider to a TClientDatset.

My issue is the resulting field in the TClientDataset ends up as ReadOnly.
The TClientDataset is created at design time to link into grids etc.  The other components are created at runtime in a separate object.

I have had a similar setup working , but with everything created at design time.  I resolve this problem by creating persistent fields on the TADOQuery component and setting the CheckField's ReadOnly property to False prior to opening the TClientDatset.  I am unsure as to how to do this at runtime given the field component doesn't exist until I have opened the ClientDatset and by then it's too late to set it's readonly property!

Comment: So you are not trying to write that field into the database? It is only for housekeeping the checks at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `CAST()`.

The dataset doesn't analyze what the underlying field might be that's being `CAST`; it just knows that it's a function result that is placed into the column, and you can't edit a function result.

You could just `SELECT *, 0 AS CheckField`, and then set a validation on the resulting field to restrict the values to `0` and `1`.